# How does pytest.approx accomplish its magic?

Tags: python, pytest

The pytest `approx` function seems really, cool, and as they say in their [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-approx) it uses a really intuitive syntax:

```py
>>> from pytest import approx
>>> 0.1 + 0.2 == approx(0.3)
True
```

```py
>>> 1 + 1e-8 == approx(1)
True
```

But how does this actually *work*? In the first example, let's say the left side reduces to something like `0.29999...`, so how can I have something on the right side that evaluates to being equal to it? Does the `approx` function somehow know how to look at the lvalue of the `==` operator? The fact that `approx` actually works seems like pure sorcery, can someone explain how it accomplishes its neat little trick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a standard datamodel hook into a custom [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).

The simplified example below should clarify the "sorcery" for you.

```
>>> class MyObj: 
...     def __eq__(self, other): 
...         print(self, "is being compared with", other) 
...         return "potato" 
...
>>> obj = MyObj()   
>>> 0.1 + 0.2 == obj
<__main__.MyObj object at 0xcafef00d> is being compared with 0.30000000000000004
'potato'
```

Note that `float.__eq__` will get the first attempt at handling this comparison. The behavior shown above, and also for `approx(0.3)`, crucially relies on the fact that `float` has explicitly "opted out" of comparing with `MyObj` instances. It does this by returning a special value [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented):

```
>>> (0.1+0.2).__eq__(obj)
NotImplemented
```

For the actual pytest implementation, look in [`python_api.py::ApproxScalar`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/4.5.0/src/_pytest/python_api.py#L223).

Comment: +1 for a super-helpful example, thank you. Yeah I had forgotten about the ability to overload `__eq__`. You raise a really good point -- both the lvalue and the rvalue have a shot at overloading the behavior of `==`, and it's vitally important that the rvalue "wins" here in order for the code to function as intended!

Answer (score 2):

From the source code I could find that they create corresponding Approx version of the classes. For example, they have `ApproxDecimal`, `ApproxScalar`, `ApproxMapping` and so on. The approx function checks the type of the value you pass and then assigns it a corresponding approximate class that they have defined.

So when you enter:

```
0.1 + 0.2 == approx(0.3)
```

the approx changes it to:

```
0.1 + 0.2 == ApproxDecimal(0.3)
```

Now these Approx classes implement corresponding `__eq__()` and `__repr__()` functions that help python perform the comparison. Hence they are able to define the logic for approximate matching within these Approximate classes.

Comment: Yeah the important part I was looking for was the fact that it's leveraging the `__eq__` function.